# SQL select query to get records based on xml node value?

Tags: sql, xml

I have a column of ntext data type and NOT XML. It stores all xml data. I need to get records based on xml node value.
=>input value is CpsiaId = 456 and should return all records which has this value in the xml

I tried `select * from tableName
where convert(xml,column_name).value('data((/root/ProductInformation/CPSIA/CpsiaDetails/Item/CpsiaId)[1])','int') = 456`

but it didn't work....any ideas or other way of getting the records based xml node value.

**Sample Xml:**

```
<root>
  <ProductInformation>
    <Name> Truck with Battery Charger</Name>
    <Description>Fr.</Description>
    <CPSIA>
      <CpsiaDetails>
        <Item>
          <CpsiaId>456</CpsiaId>
          <CpsiaMessage>waring</CpsiaMessage>
        </Item>
        <Item>
          <CpsiaId>236</CpsiaId>
          <CpsiaMessage>to health</CpsiaMessage>
        </Item>
      </CpsiaDetails>
    </CPSIA>
  </ProductInformation>
</root>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
convert(xml,column_name).exist('/root/ProductInformation/CPSIA/CpsiaDetails/Item[CpsiaId=456]') = 1
```

This works, and you can replace the constant (`456`) with an [`sql:variable()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188254.aspx) if you need a dynamic value, like so (assuming a numeric variable `@i`):

```
'/root/ProductInformation/CPSIA/CpsiaDetails/Item[CpsiaId=sql:variable("@i")]'
```

**Edit:**

Sample code as requested:

```
DECLARE @t nvarchar(MAX);
SET @t = '<root>
  <ProductInformation>
    <Name> Truck with Battery Charger</Name>
    <Description>Fr.</Description>
    <CPSIA>
      <CpsiaDetails>
        <Item>
          <CpsiaId>456</CpsiaId>
          <CpsiaMessage>waring</CpsiaMessage>
        </Item>
        <Item>
          <CpsiaId>236</CpsiaId>
          <CpsiaMessage>to health</CpsiaMessage>
        </Item>
      </CpsiaDetails>
    </CPSIA>
  </ProductInformation>
</root>'

DECLARE @i int;
SET @i = 456;

SELECT convert(xml,@t).exist('/root/ProductInformation/CPSIA/CpsiaDetails/Item[CpsiaId=sql:variable("@i")]')
```

Comment: @Lucero can you paste dynamic sample query ? i tried it throws an error The argument 1 of the xml data type method "exist" must be a string literal.

Comment: @user594014, I added a sample as requested. My guess is that your argument for `exist` is not a valid string (quoted with single quotes `'`).

Comment: @Lucero ...it worked as expected and thank you..which one is faster my database has 1 million records  CTE or your sample

Comment: @user594014 I've udpated my answer to use both syntaxes you should just test it and see

Comment: @user594014, I would guess that mine is faster, the CTE version does create many virtual rows with the `CROSS APPLY` and it needs more XQuery runs over the XML data and a conversion (`value` method). But sometimes the optimizer works in misterious ways... if you need better performance for running this query often you may want to look into XML indexing.

Comment: @Conrad Frix, the docs say no, but even then creating a "temporary" table with an indexed XML column just for running the query afterwards may still help with the final performance depending on the complexity of the XML documents in the million rows, and how often this value is queried for. See also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191497.aspx

Comment: @Lucero Your approach was faster and I thank you both for helping me out.

Comment: @Lucero If i want do the update the column xml node value for CpsiaMessage node based on id. For Example
Input Id: 456 and new CPsiaMessage: "Smoking is injurious to health". Is it possible through xpath?

Comment: @user594014, it is possible on XML columns (just like indexing is possible on XML columns) by using the [`modify()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187093.aspx) method of the `xml` datatype. However, as long as your column is `ntext` this will not be as easy to do.

Comment: @Lucero Thank you for the response. I found the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5954359/sql-update-query-to-update-xml-in-records-based-on-xml-node-value

Comment: @user594014 - thanks for the follow-up - note that this is exactly what I suggested doing ;)

Answer (score 0):

It may be easier to use a CTE to convert it to XML first and then do a CROSS Apply. Here's a sample

```
Declare @test table (id int identity, xmlData nvarchar(max))
Insert Into @test 
(xmldata)
Values 
('<root>
  <ProductInformation>
    <Name> Truck with Battery Charger</Name>
    <Description>Fr.</Description>
    <CPSIA>
      <CpsiaDetails>
        <Item>
          <CpsiaId>456</CpsiaId>
          <CpsiaMessage>waring</CpsiaMessage>
        </Item>
        <Item>
          <CpsiaId>236</CpsiaId>
          <CpsiaMessage>to health</CpsiaMessage>
        </Item>
      </CpsiaDetails>
    </CPSIA>
  </ProductInformation>
</root>'),
('<root>
  <ProductInformation>
    <Name> Truck with Battery Charger</Name>
    <Description>Fr.</Description>
    <CPSIA>
      <CpsiaDetails>
        <Item>
          <CpsiaId>999</CpsiaId>
          <CpsiaMessage>waring</CpsiaMessage>
        </Item>
        <Item>
          <CpsiaId>123</CpsiaId>
          <CpsiaMessage>to health</CpsiaMessage>
        </Item>
      </CpsiaDetails>
    </CPSIA>
  </ProductInformation>
</root>')

;with cte as (select id, convert(xml,t.xmlData) xdata from @test t )
SELECT t.*
     from cte inner join @test t
     on cte.id = t.id
    cross apply cte.xdata.nodes('//root/ProductInformation/CPSIA/CpsiaDetails/Item') x(nd)
WHERE
    x.nd.value('CpsiaId[1]','int') =456
```

Using Lucero's answer for the Select against a table (rather than an xml variable)

```sql
DECLARE @i int;
SET @i = 456;
SELECT * 
FROM 
    @test 
WHERE
    convert(xml,xmlData).exist('/root/ProductInformation/CPSIA/CpsiaDetails/Item[CpsiaId=sql:variable("@i")]') = 1
```

Comment: @Conrad Frix ...it worked as expected and thank you..which one is faster my database has 1 million records  your sample or below another post by Lucero

Comment: @user594014. I would guess that Lucero's would be better but its just a guess. I would try both and see

Comment: @ConradFrix Yes, you guess was right lucero's approach was faster and I thank you both for helping me out.

Comment: @ConradFrix thanks i found the answer key and kind of hidden.. by the way how do you guys retain color syntax when you copy from visual studio or sql server in the editor...i was never succesfull..can you tell me?

Comment: @user594014 You select the code block and press the `{}` button. You can also use [Markdown](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-overflow-server-fault-and-super-user). If you feel like experimenting you can go to the [Markdown Sandbox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Comment: @ConradFrix...If i want do the update the column value for CpsiaMessage node based on id. For Example
Input Id: 456 and InputMessage: "Smoking is injurious to health". Is it possible through xpath?